# Reduce apache configuration file (similar virtual hosts)

Tags: apache-2.4

I have many sites to configure, each domain targets a specific department, so my virtual host segments are practically the same, I already optimized with include directive, but I think there are other things to squeeze down.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain-department-1.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-department-1.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/domain-department-1.com">
        Include  conf.d/folder-config.conf
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.domain-department-2.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/domain-department-2.com

    <Directory "/var/www/html/domain-department-2.com">
        Include  conf.d/folder-config.conf
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use mod_vhost_alias, it's heavily documented
https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/vhosts/mass.html